# Django not matching unicode in url

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unicode

I have a problem with django 2.0, where a url that contains a unicode slug isn't matched, I searched for a solution but I didn't find one for my case, here's a simplified version of my code:

```
// models.py

class Level(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, allow_unicode=True)
```

in my urls file I have those patterns:

```
// urls.py

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('level/<slug:level_slug>', views.level, name='level')]
```

Now if I go, say to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/level/deuxième` I get this error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/level/deuxi%C3%A8me

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

game/ [name='index']
game/level/<slug:level_slug> [name='level']
admin/
accounts/
The current path, game/level/deuxième, didn't match any of these.
```

but if I change the item's slug to `deuxieme` without the unicode character, it works fine, does anyone know the solution to this problem? thanks!

Comment: Slugs never contain non-ASCII characters. If you want to match non-ASCII characters then don't use the slug.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams but I am using django 2.0 which should support non-ASCII characters, it does have the `allow_unicode` parameter.

Comment: ["slug - Matches any slug string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers, plus the hyphen and underscore characters."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This is so confusing, what's `allow_unicode` used for?

Comment: For allowing Unicode in the `SlugField`.

Comment: But why isn't it allowed in the path url then? is it useless then?

Comment: Because you're using a path converter that explicitly excludes non-ASCII.

Comment: Ok got it, I just changed `slug` to `str` and it worked, thank you very much for your help bro :-)

Comment: I have a similar problem, but using str instead of slug does not help.

Answer (score 16):

In `urls.py` change [path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) from using `slug` type to `str`.

From this:

```
    path('posts/<slug:slug>-<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view()),
```

to this:

```
    path('posts/<str:slug>-<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view()),
```

---

## Explanation

As suggested in comments, the `slug` path converter

> Matches any slug string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers, plus the hyphen and underscore characters. For example, building-your-1st-django-site.

but we want to keep those non-ascii characters, so we use `str`:

> str - Matches any non-empty string, excluding the path separator, '/'. This is the default if a converter isn’t included in the expression.

Comment: Does not work. The current path, api/v1/posts/, didn't match any of these. You can see the error removed non-English address after posts/.

Comment: I just want to thank you for this comment/solution. I never would've guessed it, since I have my slugfield's set for allowing UTF-8 & therefore "knew" it required me to use <slug:> in the path. I was going bananas trying to figure out how to regex the path until you said that <str:> works for this. Thanks!

Comment: @Zamphatta I'm glad it was helpful, I've spent some time figuring it out too, also wrote a post about slugs in Django at https://simpleit.rocks/python/django/generating-slugs-automatically-in-django-easy-solid-approaches/#2-ensure-uniqueness] which I think it may be useful. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`unidecode`](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) library, and set the `slug` field by results of `unidecode.unidecode` function, this library support many of languages and detect language automatically and then replace original characters by english characters.
For example if you want convert "Hello" word in china language to english characters, try below code:

```
$ pip install unidecode
$ python -c "import unidecode; print('---->', unidecode.unidecode('你好'))"
----> Ni Hao
```