# Django slugfield changes unicode characters when saving and causes reverse no match error

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-unicode

I'm trying to create Unicode slugs with Django. The problem arises when it tries to save and resolve URLs with said slugs with Unicode characters in it. When I checked, Django seems to modify the characters when `SlugField` is used.

This is my models.py:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, allow_unicode=True)
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    # Cat
    path('', views.CatList.as_view(), name='cat-list'),
    path('create/', views.CatCreate.as_view(), name='cat-create'),
    path('<slug:cat_slug>/', views.CatDetail.as_view(), name='cat-detail'),
    path('<slug:cat_slug>/edit/', views.CatEdit.as_view(), name='cat-edit'),

    # Post
    path('<slug:cat_slug>/posts/', views.CatDetail.as_view(), name='post-list'),    
    path('<slug:cat_slug>/posts/create/', views.PostCreate.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('<slug:cat_slug>/posts/<slug:post_slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('<slug:cat_slug>/posts/<slug:post_slug>/edit/', views.PostEdit.as_view(), name='post-edit')
]
```

And I use `slugify(slug, allow_unicode=True)` to auto-generate `slug` from `title`.

So to test this I used `தமிழ்` as `title`. Instead of a successful redirect to the URL `/cats/test-cat/posts/தமிழ்/` Django showed `NoReverseMatch` exception with the following message.

```
Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '('test-cat', 'zw93tz-தமழ')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cats/(?P<cat_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/posts/(?P<post_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

When I check the database, the `title` field has the right characters `தமிழ்` but the `slug` field has the modified characters `தமழ`.

When I looked up for solutions, I found [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51581700/1649171) to use `<str>` instead of `<slug>` in `urls.py`.

Why is this happening with `<slug>` and how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show your `urls.py` containing the path definition?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte, added the urls.py.

Comment: @Ken, did you found a solution?

Comment: @shawnngtq, I ended up converting it to ASCII using `anyascii`.